# Using LINQ to return element in Collection, would like to return Nothing if element not found

Tags: vb.net, linq

I would like the following function to return Nothing if the element with the specified key is not in the collection. Instead, it returns an error - something to the effect of "no element found"

```
Public Class MyCollection

    Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of MyType)

    Public Function FindByActivityKey(ByVal searchValue As Integer) As MyType
        Return (From P In Me Order By P.ActivityPin.PrimaryKey = searchValue).First
    End Function

End Class
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `First()` with `FirstOrDefault()` as in

```
Return (From P In Me Order By P.ActivityPin.PrimaryKey = searchValue) _
       .FirstOrDefault()
```

`First()` assumes there is at least one element and throws an exception if it can't find any. `FirstOrDefault()` returns `Nothing` by default.